# Rails flash message with ajax and jquery noty plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I made comments for profile with ajax. When someone add comment page doesn't reload so i have problem with flash messages.

My comments_controller look like this:

```
@comment = @profile.comments.includes(:user).new(params[:comment])
if @comment.save
  flash[:add_comment_success] = "Comment added"
  respond_to do |format|

    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    format.js
  end

else
```

My create.js.erb for creating comments with flash messages look like this:

```
var flashError = "<%=flash[:add_comment_success]%>";
if (flashError){
  $("#flash_messages").html("<div class='messages_notify'><div id='message-add_comment_success'><p class='message_content'>" +flashError +  "</p></div></div>");
}
```

And my app.js look like this:

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
  noty_load();
});

function noty_load(){

$( ".messages_notify #message-add_comment_success" ).each( function(){
    generate('success', 'comment added');
});
```

}

I think that there is a problem with ajax load. I must somehow check in app.js if ajax was loaded and then run noty_load() . When i check in firebug i see flash notice but noty just dont see it without page reload. How can i run noty_load when ajax request was made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `noty_load()` right at the end of create.js.erb. If you want to use a DRyer approach, you could use a layout for all your js responses like this:

application.js.erb:

```
<%= yield %>;
<% if flash.present? %>
  <% flash_message = flash.first %>
  $("#flash_messages").html("<div class='messages_notify'><div id='message-<%= j(flash_message.first) %>'><p class='message_content'><%= j(flash_message.last) %></p></div></div>");
  noty_load();
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok it works but how can i remove notification ? On page when i add comment there is only one notification, but when i reload it or go somewhere alse it generate next 3 noty

Comment: $(document).unbind('ajaxComplete'); when i do this it show only one more noty (not 3 but one extra noty) how remove extra noty at all

Comment: @Michael Check my edited answer. I added `.remove()` at the end of the showing function so it will remove the messages right after they are displayed. You don't need to unbind.

Comment: it works like unbind - i still have one extra noty on page reload.

Comment: @Michael try adding `event` as parameter to the event handler and the following line before `noty_load`: `console.log(event.type);` to see how the events are triggering.

Comment: hm it just remove #message-add_comment_success but not .messages_notify

Comment: 3 ajaxComplete - this console return

Comment: @Michael hum, try removing the errors before showing the notifications to get rid of any race conditions: `.remove().each(...`. Anyway, it seems to be related to the fact that `page:change` fires with the same request that `ajaxComplete`.
Another solution would be to go back where you started and just add `noty_load()` at the end of `create.js.erb`.

Comment: is it BAD writting in javascript ? it works but is this correct solution ?

Comment: @Michael It is always better to keep js responses to a minimum or you would end up responding with the same chunk of code to each request. I edited my answer with a DRYer approach that should handle all your flash types.